# How to close Catel Framework Datawindow from the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, catel, datawindow

Does anyone know how to close (or save) the data window from your viewmodel and not use the ok or cancel button but custom buttons like this:

```
public class UploadWindow : DataWindow
{
    public UploadWindow()
        : base(DataWindowMode.Custom)
    {
        AddCustomButton(new DataWindowButton("Ok", "???"));
        AddCustomButton(new DataWindowButton("Cancel", "???"));

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So i can do something extra before closing or saving other than the normal stuff. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the VM:

Option 1:

```
this.SaveAndCloseViewModelAsync();
```

Option 2:

```
this.CancelAndCloseViewModelAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to fix my biggest issues! But no changes that where made to this "dialogResult object" `typeFactory.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<VisitorRegistrationClosingWindowViewModel>(dialogResult);` were saved when i call `this.SaveAndCloseViewModelAsync();`

Comment: Are you using Show or ShowDialog? DialogResult is only set when using ShowDialog.

Comment: i'm using ´await _uiVisualizerService.ShowDialogAsync(visitorRegistrationClosingWindowViewModel)´

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't save the dialogResult property?

Comment: No, it should store it. Please create an issue in the issue tracker.